# How to wait untill UpsertData is done using SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs

I'm running a for loop to update some DE records.

Since the `LookupRows` is limited to 2000 records, we sometimes need it to iterate again.
Therefore the `for` loop is in a  `while` loop.
Rows are marked in a flag once updated so they won't be retrieved twice, and `while` loop should be broken at some point.

The thing is, apparently the `LookupRows` is retrieving rows even if they were flagged.
I noticed that MC is updating the flags too slow, so the `while` loop is endless...

I was thinking of adding a timer, but this sounds just like an ugly patch.
Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
var OrdersDE = Platform.Function.LookupRows('Update_new_orders','Update_Status','false');
    
while (flag){
    for (var i = 0; i < OrdersDE.length; i++) {
        SID = OrdersDE[i].User_ID__c

        newTickets = Platform.Function.Lookup('Users_Current_Tickets','Tickets','User_ID__c',SID) + 5;
        
        Platform.Function.UpsertData("Users_Current_Tickets",["User_ID__c"],[SID],["Tickets"], [newTickets]);
        Platform.Function.UpsertData("Update_new_orders",["User_ID__c"],[SID],["Update_Status"], ['true']);
    }
    OrdersDE = Platform.Function.LookupRows('Update_new_orders','Update_Status','false');
    if (!OrdersDE.length) {
        flag = false
    }else{
        Write('in else block: '+ OrdersDE.length)
        Write('OrdersDE: '+Stringify(OrdersDE));
    }
    flag = false
}
```

I can see in the `Write` section that it's actually retrieving values that were marked with a `true` falge.

```
Write('in else block: '+ OrdersDE.length)
Write('OrdersDE: '+Stringify(OrdersDE));
``
```

Comment: Hi, can you give some context to understand the options better - Is this in an automation? Can you use SQL, or two SQL queries instead? Whenever trying to circumvent the 2000 row limit, I would ask first whether I HAVE to use script, because that is exactly what the limit seems to be intended to prevent me from doing. If that is still the case, then batching / scripts might be a thing.

Comment: @JonasLamberty Yes, it's an automation script. We need to calculate some values and update the DE (not in the example script to simplify it) I think worst case we would have 5000 records. Doing the calculation in SQL is a bit tricky ...

Comment: Also use the proxy functions, they are better in performance as compared to Platform functions

Comment: The Limit is 2500 not 2000.

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick, according to the documentation and my tests it's 2000 https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDataExtensionLookupRows.htm

Comment: Maybe i switched things up with WSProxy calls then. But i dealt a lot more with 2500 limits than with a 2000 one. 2000 barely came across for me

Comment: The issue is likely around the OOO of AMPScript/SSJS in that the Lookup, Insert and Upsert functions are usually grouped together and not run in the normal cascading context. So in this case, the Upsert would be run after all the lookups are finished running. Meaning that despite the lookup being after the upsert inside the cascade, it would actually be run prior to anything being changed by that upsert. If you shifted to WSProxy or API, I think it might work more as expected, but you then run into processing draws, etc.